# Method response with timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to get response from method into variable(or console in my example) if method has some delay?

```
testMethod = (number) => {

    setTimeout(function() {
         return number+number;      
    }.bind(this), 100);        
}

testMethod2 = (number) => {

         return number+number;              
}
```

calling functions

```
console.log(this.requests.current.testMethod(44)) 
console.log(this.requests.current.testMethod2(44))
```

testMethod returns undefined

testMethod returns 88

how to get output from testMethod?

Comment: You do have to wait for it. If using ajax there is success function use that

Comment: You can use a promise or a callback. E.g. `testMethod = (number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(number + number), 100)); this.requests.current.testMethod(44).then(console.log);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your `testMethod`. What you return inside of the function given to `setTimeout` will not be returned from `testMethod`, since `setTimeout` is asynchronous.

You can use a promise or a callback for asynchronous logic.

**Promise**

```js
const testMethod = (number) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(number + number);
  }, 100);    
}

testMethod(44).then(console.log);
```

**Callback**

```js
testMethod = (number, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(number + number);      
  }, 100);        
}

testMethod(44, console.log)
```

Comment: How to get promise value into variable? if i try var xx = this.requests.current.testMethod().then(xx);  i get promise object

Comment: @Bobek You can't get value from asynchronous logic like that in JavaScript. You need to do your logic in the function given to `then` instead, e.g. `this.requests.current.getSessionID().then(result => { var xx = result; });`

Answer (score 0):

The problem, is that you function testMethod returns nothing, i.e. undefined
You can use, as suggested by Tholle use promise:

```
testMethod = (number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(function() {
             resolve(number + number);      
          }, 100); 
    });       
}

testMethod2 = (number) => {
         return number+number;              
}

this.requests.current.testMethod(44).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
console.log(this.requests.current.testMethod2(44))
```